# Rotation and Translation with the mouse in 3D view stopped to work

Tags: 3d-view

I had Blender 2.9 and I noticed that I could not rotate and translate around the object with the middle mouse and the Shift + middle move shortcuts.

I installed Blender 3.2 but I still have the same problem. I have tried different solutions found online but nothing works.

I have tried on different Blender files, I still have the same problems and I use the default settings (no custom).

Do you know how to fix this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried with another mouse? - That sounds like a hardware problem to me!

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your message.
I did and it works!

The trick is the thumbwheel of the mouse works for the zoom but the push button of the mouse does not work anymore. So I did not think about it. 

Now it is solved. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to hear it! Something that you never expect to go wrong! :^)